# unlocking a vba project with vba, knowing the password?

Tags: vba, excel, passwords

I think that question has been asked in different ways. But I didn't found a satisfying solution. I want to unlock a VBA-project using vba code. Possibly something like the .unprotect method for workbooks or -sheets. I know the password, I do not need to crack open the project.

Is there a simple way to realise this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not possible. The Password is not exposed in the VBA Object, so you cant directly access it trough VBA Code. There is only a method to send the keys for the password, but i wouldnt recommend it.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I guess it will work also without it, I do not want to bother with it for too long. have a great day!